# Check which Dropbox files are currently syncing

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to see *which* files are being currently synced? (Searching around for badged icons won't work.)

For example, large files that are within different folders that just got added to the queue.

Comment: For your votes: https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/7214/show-files-being-currently-up-downloaded-with-setting-priority-on-files https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/4982/visual-indication-of-all-files-currently-incoming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not possible.

[Can't see it](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=52994) on the web interface or on any of the apps on linked devices.

Your only near option currently is to see what has been done after the fact by checking out the [recent events page on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/events).

Answer (score 8):

For anyone looking at this question in 2014+, you can now see what is being synced (on a Mac at least—I don't know the answer for Windows, but I'm sure someone will provide that answer).

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and click on the Dropbox icon in menubar. This will show you what is currently being synced.

Comment: Not working on macOS 10.12 (2017).

Answer (score 5):

If you're under Linux, type this in the command-line:

```
find ~/Dropbox -type f -exec dropbox filestatus {} \; | grep 'syncing'
```

Comment: This solution [for Mac] would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to figure out the same thing. best I've got so far is to **look at the sync icons on the folders**.

You can at least narrow it down to **"which folder contains the files which are currently syncing"**...

In my case it's the "Camera Uploads" folder, so I'm going to look on the dropbox website to see what the largest files in that folder are... then check whether they're on my local machine. probably some videos or something.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, the way to see what's still to sync is to look in your file system Explorer.  There, there will be your Dropbox folder and those files or folders containing files will have a blue sync icon versus those already uploaded successfully with a green check mark.

Now, it's also possible to see the latest upload events by clicking on the Dropbox icon in the system tray, or to track events online, but afaik, there's no way to see what file will be syncing next.

Answer (score 0):

To Dropbox Linux client, it cannot get syncing detail like mac and windows, if syncing files count > 1, `Dropbox status` only show "downloading n files" so I use following solution:

**Reason:**

It only occurs in my unity3d project, I don't know why.

**In short:**

Create empty dirs for `downloading files` will fix.

**For detail**

**to single dir:**

`dropbox status` will show dir name

Find this dir name in Dropbox web

In local, create empty dir that same with online dir path, it will fix it.

**to multi dirs**

`dropbox status` will show "downloading n files"

I cannot find the path/to/dir

So use following way:

To Dropbox root, `dropbox filestatus`, it will show "syncing" dir, enter "syncing" dir.

Recursive do above, until find the dir that status is "syncing" but all child status is "up-to-date", call "err-dir".

That's the problem, since parent show "syncing", but all child show "up to date"
the reason is, some cloud site dirs or files doesn't create correctly in local side.

open "err-dir" in dropbox web, compare online err-dir childs with local err-dir child, the missing dir in local err-dirs child, it's I should create.

**Tip**

Online err-dir child can selection all by mouse, use code convert it to array, local err-dir child can be list by `ls`, convert it to array, compare them.

Answer (score 0):

With Linux, you can run these commands:

1. ensure you are in the Dropbox folder:

```
cd ~/Dropbox/
```

2. move to the folder you want to check file(s) if needed, then enter this specific command for Dropbox under Linux:

```
dropbox status
```

=> as a result, you should get feedback like "up to date" or "syncing" (and probably others I have not received yet)

*(this is a complementary information to what @Praetore has posted)*

In any case, I find this page very helpful:
https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/linux-commands